# What is the consensus mechanism used in Parity for 'Proof of Authority' chains?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, consensus, proof-of-authority

The Ethcore Parity wiki states that it supports 'Proof of Authority Chains'. What distributed byzantine consensus mechanism is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No actual consensus mechanism is used.

Some nodes/keys have the right to sign blocks (configured in the example json you see at https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Proof%20of%20Authority%20Chains ), others don't.

As the text says, this is only for demo/development purposes.  An actual consensus mechanism will need to be plugged in later.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [now Parity is called OpenEthereum](https://www.parity.io/blog/parity-ethereum-openethereum-dao/), which includes a consortium consensus algorithm called [Aura](https://openethereum.github.io/Aura)